# How do I append a PDF file from binary to an already 'in-progress' PDF, using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

In code, I am in the process of created a PDF document using iTextSharp. I have already added content to the document and have closed the document, successfully retrieving it in a response to a web browser.

What I am trying to do is append another PDF document to the one I am creating but it has to come from binary or an object of type `Byte[]`.

I realize that there is the available method `document.Add(stuff)` but I am trying to convert the binary to an object and then essentially add that to the document in progress. I have seen questions and posts similar to my scenario but they are mostly dealing with Images.

**Here is what I have...**

```
while (sqlExpDocDataReader.Read())
{
    // Read data and fill temp. objects
    string docName = sqlExpDocDataReader["docName"].ToString();
    string docType = sqlExpDocDataReader["docType"].ToString();
    Byte[] docData = (Byte[])sqlExpDocDataReader["docData"];

    // Get current page size
    var pageWidth = document.PageSize.Width;
    var pageHeight = document.PageSize.Height;

    // Is this an image or PDF?
    if (docType.Contains("pdf"))
    {
        // Could I use a memeory stream some how?
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(docData.ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        // Here I see how to do it with images.
        Image doc = Image.GetInstance(docData);
        doc.ScaleToFit(pageWidth, pageHeight); // width, height
        document.Add(doc);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit more digging, here is how I was able to resolve my issue...

Basically, I created a `MemoryStream` object from my binary data and then created a `PdfReader` to read that object, where normally we would read a file. 
I then looped through each page of the reader object (or file if you'd like) and appended them as they where found.

```
if (docType.Contains("pdf"))
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(docData.ToArray());
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
        document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly, it appears we can use the same method for adding pages that would for images.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] UnificarImagenesPDF(IEnumerable<DocumentoDTO> documentos)// "documents" is a list of objects that are located in the database, the images and pdf are stored in a binary attribute of "documents" 
{
 using (MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
  iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();//to create a itextSharp Document
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream);
  doc.Open();
  foreach (DocumentoDTO d in documentos)// "documentos" has an attribute where the document extension type is saved (eg pdf, jpg, png, etc) 
  {
   try
   {
    if (d.sExtension == ".pdf")
  {
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(d.bBinarios.ToArray());
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms); // 
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
   {
   PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
   doc.Add(resizeImagen(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page)));//Each sheet of the PDF document is added to the document created in itextsharp, and the resizeImage function is used so that the images are centered in the ITEXTSHARP document
   doc.NewPage();// add a new page on ITEXTSHARP document
   }
  }
if (d.sExtension != ".pdf")
 {
  doc.Add(resizeImagen(Image.GetInstance((byte[])d.bBinarios)));
  doc.NewPage();
 }
}
 catch
 {  }
}
   doc.Close();
   writer.Close();
   return workStream.ToArray();
}
}

private static iTextSharp.text.Image resizeImagen(iTextSharp.text.Image image)
{
   if (image.Height > image.Width)
   {
   //Maximum height is 800 pixels.
   float percentage = 0.0f;
   percentage = 700 / image.Height;
   image.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
   }
   else
   {
  //Maximum width is 600 pixels.
  float percentage = 0.0f;
  percentage = 540 / image.Width;
  image.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
   }
  return image;
}
```

Comment: Esta función agrega en un solo documento de itextsharp, imagenes y pdf's provenientes de una base de datos que fueron guardadas en formato binario.

This function adds in a single document of itextsharp, images and pdf's from a database that were saved in binary format.

Comment: Please add more explanation!

Comment: @Afsanefda I hope these comments help you, if you have any specific questions, let me know